# how to store output to list in for loop in r

Tags: r

I am doing web scraping of a website. When I fetch the data from a website every page has 10 observations. I am writing a function where you can specify no of pages to scrape and finally store it in a list and later convert it into dataframe.

```
library(jsonlite)
forum_data_fetch <- function(no_of_pages) {

   pages <- seq(no_of_pages)
   #print(pages)
   forum_data <- list()

   for(i in 1:length(pages)){
       tmp <- fromJSON(paste("http://mmb.moneycontrol.com/index.php?q=topic/ajax_call&section=get_messages&offset=&lmid=&isp=0&gmt=cat_lm&catid=1&pgno=",i,sep=""))
       forum_data[[i]] <- tmp

  }

   dat <- as.data.frame(forum_data)
   dat <- dat[,c("msg_id","border_msg_count","user_id","border_level_text","follower_count", "topic", "tp_sector","tp_msg_count","heading", "flag", "price", "message")]

 return(dat)

}

 test <- forum_data_fetch(3)
```

Ideally, the above function returns 30 observations, but it returns only 10. I think I am doing something wrong while storing the list as a data.frame

Comment: It seems the problem is `dat <- as.data.frame(forum_data)`, replace it with `dat <- lapply(forum_data, as.data.frame) %>% rbindlist` (`data.table` and `dplyr` packages are used).

Comment: But,my forum_data contains only one list element. Ideally it should contain 3 elements.

Comment: Yes, it has 3 elements. Please see my modified code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding new rows to existing columns, `as.data.frame(forum_data)` adds new columns (i.e. variables) with the same names.. Use `do.call(rbind, forum_data)` instead:

```
dat1 <- as.data.frame(forum_data)
str(dat1)
# data.frame':  10 obs. of  219 variables:
# $ TOTAL_MSG_CNT             : int  50000 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
# $ msg_id                    : chr  "47754017" "47754014" "47751119" "47746189" ...
# $ user_id                   : chr  "rajeshatharv" "bullbuffet" "csr93" "sanjiv3312" ...
# .... 

dat2 <- do.call(rbind, forum_data)
str(dat2)
# 'data.frame': 30 obs. of  73 variables:
#  $ TOTAL_MSG_CNT           : int  50000 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
# $ msg_id                  : chr  "47754017" "47754014" "47751119" "47746189" ...
# $ user_id                 : chr  "rajeshatharv" "bullbuffet" "csr93" "sanjiv3312" ...
# ....
```

Then just select the columns you want to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it works:

```
forum_data_fetch <- function(no_of_pages) {
  require(data.table)
  require(dplyr)
  pages <- seq(no_of_pages)
  forum_data <- list()

  for(i in 1:length(pages)){
    tmp <- fromJSON(paste("http://mmb.moneycontrol.com/index.php?q=topic/ajax_call&section=get_messages&offset=&lmid=&isp=0&gmt=cat_lm&catid=1&pgno=",i,sep=""))
    forum_data[[i]] <- tmp

  }
  cat("the length of forum_data is", length(forum_data), "\n")
  dat <- lapply(forum_data, as.data.frame) %>% rbindlist
  dat <- dat[,c("msg_id","border_msg_count","user_id","border_level_text","follower_count", "topic", "tp_sector","tp_msg_count","heading", "flag", "price", "message")]

  return(dat)

}

test <- forum_data_fetch(3)
dim(test)
```

The console output looks like

```
> test <- forum_data_fetch(3)
the length of forum_data is 3 
> dim(test)
[1] 30 12
```